# What is the difference betweeen Intent(getApplicationContext(), class) and Intent(class)

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on a code as a reference and encountered this Intent call: `Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class)`

I got baffled because in my projects I only use: `Intent(".mYSecondActivity")`
I tried removing `getApplicationContext()` and changed it to `Intent(".secondActivity")'` in which the name is registered in the manifest. I run the application and Forced Closed. What is the significance of `getApplicationContext()`?

`secondActivity.class` is coded to retrieve data from a PHP MYSQL database.

Comment: When you move from one activity to another activity then you have to pass context from 1st activity to 2nd activity because both has different view and 2nd activity must have its own context.

Comment: [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext())

Comment: Check provided link in my answer, you'll understand significance of every method of getContext.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what context mean. Is it some form of data? @ManishAndroid

Comment: Context is a kind of base in form of object. It can be a base of application or a base of activity. Everything in android runs according to base. Like if you want to show a dialog so it needs context a base on which that dialog will be shown. so If you are getting application context you get the base of whole application but if you are getting activity context you will get activity base

Comment: The answers here are all over the place. If you are starting activities by using `Intent(".mYSecondActivity")` then you must be defining intent-filters for all your activities. This is most probably **not** what you want to be doing. Please post your manifest so we can check this.

Comment: Actually, the significance of `Context` is probably irrelevant to this question. The real question should be: What is the difference between `new Intent("string")` and `new Intent(context, activity.class)` ? and actually, there is a big difference!

Comment: @ David Wasser - here is the manifest

`<activityandroid:name=".MainScreenActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".AllProductsActivity"
android:label="All Products" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".NewProductActivity"
android:label="Add New Product" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".EditProductActivity"
android:label="Edit Product" >
</activity>`

Comment: @ David Wasser - I have been searching all night and I can't find a plain explanation in their difference. All I found are code snippets. No explanations.

Answer (score 0):

"This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you."
source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29