# why , context is used in android with buttons and setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I am facing this problem and i want to find the reason that what is the need of passing this , to button & setOnClickListener .

Comment: Because its syntax is like that

Comment: Views need a context reference to the activity.

Comment: Refer to my answer, This will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996466/what-is-the-difference-betweeen-intentgetapplicationcontext-class-and-inten/14996494#14996494

Comment: Am i true i :-- context is same as "this" in java .

Answer (score 5):

**Context** is interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

**Button** is also resource of application so if you want to create button or any widget then you have to pass Context in constructor of widget.

For more [details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)