# Why cant I display a new activity? (intent)

Tags: android

I cannot figure out why my new activity wont start (I have omitted all the irrelevant code)

I am trying to display a main menu once the time has ended

```
public class GRenderer implements Renderer 
{

    public void timer ()
     {
        Game.currentGameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Game.ellapsedTime = Game.currentGameTime - Game.gameStartTime;

        if (Game.ellapsedTime > 10000)
        {
            // THIS IS WHEN The GAME SHOULD END
            Toast.makeText(Game.context, "10Seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent MainMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class); 
            startActivity(MainMenu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) // when drawing to screen
    {
        timer();
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1386

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184): Process: com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter, PID: 20184

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184): java.lang.NullPointerException

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter.GameLoop.timer(GameLoop.java:280)

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter.GameLoop.onDrawFrame(GameLoop.java:296)

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)

12-13 18:28:28.500: E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: try using `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only start an activity from another activity . Seems like GRenderer is not your activity.you should pass this to your GLSurfaceView activity.

Comment: how said this @nitesh?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan in this declaration "public class GRenderer implements Renderer " i am not seeing any activity .

Comment: You can also start Activities from Service and BroadcastReceivers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service

Comment: He's getting a NullPointerException in whatever Gameloop#timer() method is.  It's killing his Activity before it starts is my guess.

Comment: he is getting nullPointerException in java.lang.NullPointerException

 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext

Comment: because he/she try to call intent with `getApplicationContext()`, he/she must call with context of activity

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
    Intent MainMenu = new Intent(YourActivity.this,MainMenu.class); 
    startActivity(MainMenu);
```

instead of

```
    Intent MainMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class); 
    startActivity(MainMenu);
```

for more info about getApplicationContext() read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996466/what-is-the-difference-betweeen-intentgetapplicationcontext-class-and-inten)